dropout test phase probability calculation
This following slide is from Deep Learning Lecture by Justin Johnson that is accessible on Youtube.
This is part is about how to handle dropout during test time.
I derived the equation just like the green box, but it is different from the original text. What I have done wrong?


You're taking an expectation of a function $f$, which depends on 2 variables (including $z$), with respect to $z$.
The general formula for an expectation as an integral is $E_z[f(z)] = \int p(z) f(z) dz$, where $p$ is the density.
See the law of unconscious statistician.
So, it's not $p(x, y) = p(x | y) p(y)$. That's something different.

Your green box derivation is only valid for computing marginal distribution $f(x)$ from the joint probability distribution $f(x,z)$ via chain rule, assuming $f(x,z)$ is a joint distribution first. However, here for test time drop out to rid of random result from random mask $z$, the neural network mapping $f(x,z)$ is not a joint distribution but some deterministic universal approximating function.
